# Custom properties generics at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am using the next code to pass parameters to a generic method.

```
 private void SetValue<T>(T control, String title)
 {
      T.BackgroundImage = title;
 }
```

example usage

```
SetValue<Button>(myButton,"Resource.ImgHouse_32.etc")
```

this doesnt compile due at the line T.BackgroundImage, its is a property of some controls, Button, Checkbox, etc.

how can I to set a generic way for can do it T.BackGroundImage ?

sorry any error is code in the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things to make this work:

1. Constrain your generics (or remove them), and
2. Load the resource from the string

This would look like:

```
private void SetBackgroundImage<T>(T control, string title) where T : Control
{
    control.BackgroundImage = 
                new Bitmap(
                    typeof(this).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(title));
}
```

Note that, in this case, you don't need generics at all.  Since `Control` has the [`BackgroundImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, you can just write this as:

```
private void SetBackgroundImage(Control control, string title)
{
    control.BackgroundImage = 
                new Bitmap(
                    typeof(this).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(title));
}
```

You could then call this via:

```
SetBackgroundImage(myButton, "MyProject.Resources.ImgHouse_32.png"); // Use appropriate path
```

Comment: Wow I see my code error is control.backgroundimage not T.backgroundimage, I need to rest many hours!

Comment: @user2112467 You also can't assign a string to BackgroundImage - you'll need to make an Image ;)

Comment: is true! is really a Bitmap the parameter used in my code. I code it in the fly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void SetValue<T>(T control, String title) where T:Control
```

You have to tell the compiler that T inherits Control. This is called constraints I believe, and you can set this constraints to classes and interfaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Wow I see my code error is control.backgroundimage not T.backgroundimage, I need to rest many hours!, I tried many times with the code same as you I never see my error. I need to sleep. many thanks

Comment: That's not his problem. He's trying to set T.BackgroundImage instead of control.BackgroundImage. He's also trying to set it to a string instead of a Bitmap.

Comment: @trope: is really a Bitmap the parameter used in my code. I code it in the fly. Thank you.

Comment: Ah. Either way, Reed's answer above should suffice. Happy coding.